# Export database project as SQL script

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, database-schema

I have been sent a web app by someone to see if I can give them a hand with re-hosting it. I haven't worked with database projects in Visual Studio and it looks as if this app uses a database project in Visual Studio, I am looking at how to export it as SQL script so I can add create it in SQL server management studio. I have read that I can do this by going to the properties for the database project and clicking the 'deploy' tab however I don't appear to have a deploy tab! I'm guessing its down to the version of Visual Studio. I'm using 2010. How do I export the project as a SQL script file?

[image]

Comment: That looks quite different. Did you try settings?

Comment: What you see is different based on what *Type* of project you have open (or what type VS thinks it is).  The above looks like a normal Application project.  Thomas Steven's post looks like a *Data-tier Application* project.

Answer (score 6):

The following steps could be helpful:

You can try the settings tab. The environment depends on the database project type. In one of my projects I have a tab called Project Setting where it gives me the option to create a SQL script (see image below)[image]

Or in other editions of Visual Studios
1. Open the project / solution and right-click the project and select Properties or double-click on the Properties folder
2. A new window appears in your environment, showing all project properties. Now Click the Deploy tab
3. Under Deploy Action select "Create a deployment script (.sql)" from the drop-down list 
4. Hit the save button and close this window
5. From the Build menu select Build Solution and then select "Deploy [solution name]"
6. Once your script is deployed it should be available under the SQL-debug folder, 
for example: [path to my project]\sql\debug\script.sql

Comment: What version and edition of Visual Studio is this?  I think that's at least part of the difference.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, This option definitely exists in Visual Studio 2013. This could possibly be 2012, also.